# auto logging and web scraping

Tags: java, screen-scraping

I have a task where I need to autologin and scrape a particualr website.

I have seen people suggesting htmlUnit and HttpClient mostly with Java. htmlUnit looks like a testing tool. I am not sure what to do with that. Is there an example that explains auto login and web scraping with `htmlUnit` or `httpClient`?

Im a Java developer. Can anyone who closely works with it please share any ideas?

Comment: [Chapter 4. HTTP authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be broken down to

- login into the website
- Scrape the data from website.

So, for the first part-:

1. Install livehttp header firefox addon and than read all the http
   headers that were sent and received by your browser while trying to
   login.
2. Try to send these headers using your java code, basically you have
   to emulate a `HTTP POST` request using your java code. For that
       `google->make post request from java`

After you have login into the website, than scrap the data using the API of your choice.
I personally use `htmlcleaner` [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/).

To scrape data you can use `XPath expressions` with htmlcleaner.

Take a look at [Xpath+htmlcleaner](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/) and [here also](http://blog.andrewpearson.org/2010/07/android-html-parsing.html)

You can also use `JSoup` instead of `htmlcleaner`. Advantage of using JSoup is it can handle both `login[POST Request] and Data scraping`. Take a look here http://pastebin.com/E0WzpuhF

I know it seems a lot of work, i have provided you with two alternative solution for your problem but divide your problem into smaller chunks and than try to solve it.